# How to use AKS managed identity in ArgoCD to connect to ACR?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, argocd, azure-acr

I want to use user assigned or managed identity for AKS and ArgoCD to create an application.

I assigned AcrPull on my ACR for AKS identity, and then tried to create a ArgoCD repo with

```
argocd repo add myACR.azurecr.io --type helm --name helm --enable-oci
```

`helm` is the root of my repos there. It worked correctly and I can see a green "successful" tick in a connection status in ArgoCD UI.

But when I try to create an app for one of the actual images, it fails with

> `helm pull oci://myACR.azurecr.io/helm/mychart --version 0.0.1 --destination /tmp/helm706383544`
>
> failed exit status 1: Error: failed to authorize: failed to fetch
> anonymous token: unexpected status: 401 Unauthorized

(on a side note, if I enable admin user and create argocd repo with `--username XXX --password XXX` options, everything works as expected)

What am I missing? Is it possible to achieve this? Or do I need to enable admin user on ACR (or use tokens?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say AKS identity and mean the user managed identity then its wrong in this case.

For accessing the ACR you need to assign the kubelet identity of your AKS the `AcrPull` Role as the [kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/#kubelet) is responsible for pulling images:

```
export KUBE_ID=$(az aks show -g <resource group> -n <aks cluster name> --query identityProfile.kubeletidentity.objectId -o tsv)
export ACR_ID=$(az acr show -g <resource group> -n <acr name> --query id -o tsv)
az role assignment create --assignee $KUBE_ID --role "AcrPull" --scope $ACR_ID
```

But this is only the part where Kubernetes is pulling the images. I dont think that ArgoCD out-of-the-box leverages the Azure Identites to connect to your repo.

So maybe you need to specify username and password in order that ArgoCD can connect to the helm repo:

```
argocd repo add myACR.azurecr.io --type helm --name helm --enable-oci --username <username> --password <password>
```

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to avoid using users/passwords as much as I can, but if ArgoCD does not support it - I think I am out of luck

Comment: you could use FluxCD, there it is supported.

Comment: and even integrated within the azure portal and can be installed via AKS extensions

Comment: This is what I have been looking for hours! Thanks @Philip Welz!